# VS Code Debug (Node) with Telepresence

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, отладка, отладчик

- 

Ищу способ отладки сервиса в VS Code через telepresence (v. 0.109)

У нас микросервисная архитектура
Наш стэк: TS, Node, Kubernetes, Docker

Единственный знакомый способ - через Chrome:

Прописываем в терминале команду:

```
telepresence --swap-deployment <deployment name> --run-shell
```

Затем:

```
node --inspect=127.0.0.1:9229 index.js
```

После этого в Хроме открываем chrome://inspect, переходим по ссылке, открываем необходимый нам файл и расставляем точки останова. При выполнении кода будет автоматически открываться Хром на точках останова.

После обнаружения ошибки и исправления кода останавливаем работу скрипта.

Этот способ неудобен тем, что при повторном запуске необходимо снова открывать chrome://inspect и переходить по ссылке (ссылка получается одноразовая).

Пытаюсь найти способ для отладки непосредственно в VS Code, но пока безуспешно.
Изучил документацию по отладке приложений Node (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387), но ответа не нашел...
Подозреваю, что вся проблема в конфигурации файла launch.json
Я так понимаю, что по любому необходимо установить среди прочего:

```
"port": 9229,
"request": "attach"
```

Здесь я зашел в тупик...

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось не так трудно:

1. Подключаемся через telepresence через докер - `telepresence --swap-deployment <deployment name> --docker-run -ti -v` `pwd``:/app -v ~/.npmrc:/root/.npmrc --workdir /app node:14 bash`
2. Выполняем команду запуска приложения/сервиса - `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js`
3. Конфигурируем файл launch.json -

   ```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to TP",
        "port": 9229,
        "address": "0.0.0.0",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": "/app"
      }
    ]
   ```

   }

Ставим точки отанова, F5 - наслаждаемся )